# GPS stream question

Tags: gps

I have an adafruit Ultimate GPS unit, its working fine. I am reading the GPS stream, via the command line, and one of the details, is "Angle: 167.97"
I looked at [a page about GPS sentences](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/), but I'm still confused. Angle, is the direction of wind, or rudder, or angle at altitude. In this case i would guess its either rudder (because I don't know what rudder it may be referring to) or wind angle. Its changing frequently, but the device is stationary in my shed.

My questions are: What is angle referring to? as in, is it wind or rudder?
And where is it referring to? obviously, its not getting that data from its present location, so is that data coming from a whether station or something?

pardon me if this is the wrong exchange to post in, Im not sure where to ask.

Comment: Can we see the entire sentence?

Comment: It will be referring to the angle of travel. But since it's not travelling that angle is meaningless.

Comment: Sure, ill post the entire sentence soon.

Answer (score 1):

It will be referring to the angle of travel. That is, if you're moving (say driving in a car) what direction that movement is in.

But since you aren't moving the angle is meaningless. Instead it's trying to work out a direction from the random noise of the slight changes in the calculated location.

Unless your shed is in a tornado and flying through the air then the angle is not something you need to care about. Ignore it.

Comment: +1 for a sense of humor  :)